# Optimal route with timed waypoints

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to plan a route for a delivery truck with a number of stops along the way where some of the stops need to be timed. I have tried to figure out a way that makes use of the Directions service and the Distance service without making a ton of requests. If someone has got a solution in theory I can probably put together the code myself. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of the "ton of requests" way you've tried? Sometimes it helps if you show us what you've tried, and we can work from that. eg I don't know the Google Maps API, but on seeing your code I may be able to spot a logic flaw.

Comment: I haven't done any coding yet. I'm still just trying to figure out how to do it in theory before I get to work. Google's Directions service provides an optimal route with a starting point, an ending point and a number of stops in between. The Distance service provides the distance between two points. I'm thinking how I can use those two services to calculate the optimal route when some of the stops need to be on a specific time... (sorry for the lengthy answer).